# plotting stacked bar graph

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, ordereddictionary

i want to plot stacked bar graph using matplotlib and pandas.The below code plot the bargraph very nicely.However when i change a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h ..etc to January, February... it doesnot plot the same graph.It only plot alphabetical order.Are there anyway to overcome this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

years=["2016","2017","2018","2019","2020", "2021"]
dataavail={
    "a":[20,0,0,0,10,21],
    "b":[20,13,10,18,15,45],
    "c":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "d":[20,20,10,15,18,75],
    "e":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "f":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "g":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "h":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "i":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "j":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "k":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "l":[20,20,0,0,0,20],
}


df=pd.DataFrame(dataavail,index=years)

df.plot(kind="bar",stacked=True,figsize=(10,8))
plt.legend(loc="centre",bbox_to_anchor=(0.8,1.0))
plt.show()
```

But when i change the code in the portion a,b,c...to January,February... it doesnot plot the same.

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
years=["2016","2017","2018","2019","2020", "2021"]
dataavail={
    "january":[20,0,0,0,10,21],
    "February":[20,13,10,18,15,45],
    "March":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "April":[20,20,10,15,18,75],
    "may":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "June":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "July":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "August":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "September":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "October":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "November":[20,20,10,15,18,78],
    "December":[20,20,0,0,0,20],
}


df=pd.DataFrame(dataavail,index=years)

df.plot(kind="bar",stacked=True,figsize=(10,8))
plt.legend(loc="centre",bbox_to_anchor=(0.8,1.0))
plt.show()
```

Comment: `dict`'s aren't guaranteed to preserve the order of their entries, try using an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: can you please suggest how to implement orderedDict @AJBiffl

Comment: @AJBiffl which Python are you using

Comment: sir its python 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Python 3.9.7, your graphs look like the same:

```
>>> df_alpha
       a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l
2016  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20
2017   0  13  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20
2018   0  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10   0
2019   0  18  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15   0
2020  10  15  18  18  18  18  18  18  18  18  18   0
2021  21  45  78  75  78  78  78  78  78  78  78  20

>>> df_month
      January  February  March  April  may  June  July  August  September  October  November  December
2016       20        20     20     20   20    20    20      20         20       20        20        20
2017        0        13     20     20   20    20    20      20         20       20        20        20
2018        0        10     10     10   10    10    10      10         10       10        10         0
2019        0        18     15     15   15    15    15      15         15       15        15         0
2020       10        15     18     18   18    18    18      18         18       18        18         0
2021       21        45     78     75   78    78    78      78         78       78        78        20
```

Full-code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

years = ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021']

dataavail1 = {'a': [20, 0, 0, 0, 10, 21], 'b': [20, 13, 10, 18, 15, 45], 'c': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'd': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 75], 'e': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'f': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'g': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'h': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'i': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'j': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'k': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'l': [20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20]}

dataavail2 = {'January': [20, 0, 0, 0, 10, 21], 'February': [20, 13, 10, 18, 15, 45], 'March': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'April': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 75], 'may': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'June': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'July': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'August': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'September': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'October': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'November': [20, 20, 10, 15, 18, 78], 'December': [20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20]}

df_alpha = pd.DataFrame(dataavail1, index=years)
df_month = pd.DataFrame(dataavail2, index=years)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 8))
df_alpha.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, colormap=plt.cm.tab20, ax=ax1, rot=0)
df_month.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, colormap=plt.cm.tab20, ax=ax2, rot=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Update**: the code also works with Python 3.7.12

Comment: how take input here df_alpha and df_month

Comment: What do you mean? How I build your dataframe? with your code

Comment: yes sir/madam u r right

Comment: I just reused your variables `years` and `dataavail` and I built the two dataframes

Comment: if posible please post complete code...i am unable to give input to your code

Comment: I updated my answer with the full code.

Comment: Thanks @corralien...i need little more support if possible from your side.I need to plot tick marks to inside the plot and the x axis values such as 2016,2017...should be horizontal.

Comment: For years, just add `rot=0` to `plot` method. For tick marks, I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Thanks another question i have asked please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69988755/making-groupby-plot-using-matplotlib-and-pandas