# making groupby plot using matplotlib and pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, bar-chart

i have a code that plot the figure as fllows[image]

code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

years=["ASD","MNG","KQR","MND","QST", "MNR"]
dataavail={
    "Jan":[20,20,30,19,10,21],
    "Feb":[20,13,10,18,15,30],
    "Mar":[20,20,10,15,18,30],
    "Apr":[20,20,10,15,18,0],
    "May":[20,20,10,15,18,0],
    "Jun":[20,20,10,15,18,0],
    "Jul":[20,20,10,15,18,0],
    "Aug":[20,20,10,15,18,45],
    "Sep":[20,20,10,15,18,0],
    "Oct":[20,20,10,15,18,0],
    "Nov":[20,20,10,15,18,0],
    "Dec":[20,20,0,0,0,0],
}


df_month = pd.DataFrame(dataavail, index=years)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 5))
df_month.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, colormap=plt.cm.tab20, ax=ax1)
plt.legend(loc="upper right", ncol = 3,handlelength=1.5, borderpad=0.2, labelspacing=0.2) 
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

However, instead of stack plot i need the groupby plot something like as figure attached where the x-axis should be same as the first plot.can anybody help me on this.
[image]

Comment: How many years do you have to display?

Comment: only 2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021

Comment: So what is the problem with @mozway answer?

Comment: if i have many elements in x axis like ASD, MNG... suppose nearly 50 then the bars are not visible properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you want an unstacked bar plot?

```
df_month.plot.bar()
```

output:

[image: bar plot]

###### using your code:

You should remove `stacked=True` (or use `stacked=False`):

```
df_month = pd.DataFrame(dataavail, index=years)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 5))
df_month.plot(kind='bar', stacked=False, colormap=plt.cm.tab20, ax=ax1)
plt.legend(loc="upper right", ncol = 3,handlelength=1.5, borderpad=0.2, labelspacing=0.2) 
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot]

Comment: ok if i have many elements in x axis like ASD, MNG... suppose nearly 50 then the plots is not visible properly, HOW CAN THIS BE OVERCOME

Comment: Use `barh` instead of `bar`, you'll get horizontal bars this tolerates much more values